# Fastify response schema with $merge-keyword throws FST_ERR_SCH_BUILD

Tags: jsonschema, ajv, fastify

When adding a response schema to a fastify resource that leverages the `$merge` keyword, an error

```
FST_ERR_SCH_BUILD: Failed building the schema for GET: /, due error undefined unsupported
```

is thrown.

Schema looks like the following, but the same error is thrown using the examples from ajv or fastify.

```js
response: {
        200: {
            $merge: {
                source: {
                    type: 'object',
                    properties: {
                        foo: { type: 'string' }
                    }
                },
                with: {
                    type: 'object',
                    properties: {
                        bar: { type: 'string' }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

*workaround described in own answer*

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround for this:
it seems that unlike when using `$merge` in any other schema, either fastify or ajv require the `type` keyword to be present on `$merge` level.

This might be a bug, as it can be deduced from the merged objects and the methodology works when  using `$merge` for other schemas.

Answer (score 0):

The serializer doesn't implement the ajv's schema customization (as it is `$merge`). Under the hood [fast-json-stringify](https://github.com/fastify/fast-json-stringify) is used by default.

You should use standard JSON schema and its [combining keywords](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/combining.html).

In fastify v2 the serializer that uses the schemas is not customizable, so you should write your own serializer and set up it using [`setReplySerializer`](https://github.com/fastify/fastify/blob/master/docs/Server.md#setreplyserializer).